Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties annotation with @Bean on Hikari connection pool does not auto-complete properties on IntelliJ IDEA
I have the following configuration for Hikari data source on my Spring Boot application:
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.master")
    public DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.master.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource masterDataSource(@Qualifier("masterDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

When I try to configure Hikari configuration in the application.properties with the specified prefix in IntelliJ IDEA, the only thing the IDE detects is spring.datasource.master.hikari.configuration as in the screenshot

The application still works fine with the specified Hikari configuration in the screenshot, but what should I do for the IDE to correctly auto-complete the configuration properties?

What's one that's missing?

i don't see any master.hikari proeprties here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data

@RyuzakiL You can see that I was trying to apply a custom prefix @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.master.hikari") to the HikariDataSource bean, so that I could configure the Hikari connection pool in the application.properties file. As you can see in the screenshot, none of the fields in HikariDataSource class can be determined by IntelliJ but only configuration property and I want to know why and how to make it work.
